# Singular points , Poles

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I am having trouble with these 2 parts. In the back of the book the answer for the parts is [image]

For part a I expanded out sin^2 z using the taylor series expansion and found there is 0 term for the first third fifth term etc so I don't see how they are getting a pole of order 2. My view the it is a essential singularity .

For part b I changed it into exponential form but that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

For (a) and (b):

If $f $ has a zero of order $k $ at $z_0$, then $1/f $ has a pole of order $k $ at $z_0$